# How to get object of "ntSecurityDescriptor" of a active directory user

Tags: c#, asp.net, openldap

I am working on a website. I have to find the value of user can't change password property of a user. I get this link
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa746448(v=vs.85).aspx[^]
according to which I have to find "ntSecurityDescriptor" value of that user. They are using DirectoryEntry class to find that but in my case I am using LdapConnection class.
If I use entry class I was not able to make connectivity with server So that I change it to LdapConnection class. Now I don't know how to find value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I find my solution.

```
 SearchResponse response = (SearchResponse)connection.SendRequest(request);
            DirectoryAttribute attribute = response.Entries[0].Attributes["ntSecurityDescriptor"];

            if (attribute != null)
            {
                const string PASSWORD_GUID = "{ab721a53-1e2f-11d0-9819-00aa0040529b}";
                const int ADS_ACETYPE_ACCESS_DENIED_OBJECT = 6;
                bool fEveryone = false;
                bool fSelf = false;

                ActiveDs.ADsSecurityUtility secUtility = new ActiveDs.ADsSecurityUtility();
                ActiveDs.IADsSecurityDescriptor sd = (IADsSecurityDescriptor)secUtility.ConvertSecurityDescriptor((byte[])attribute[0], (int)ADS_SD_FORMAT_ENUM.ADS_SD_FORMAT_RAW, (int)ADS_SD_FORMAT_ENUM.ADS_SD_FORMAT_IID);
                ActiveDs.IADsAccessControlList acl = (ActiveDs.IADsAccessControlList)sd.DiscretionaryAcl;

                foreach (ActiveDs.IADsAccessControlEntry ace in acl)
                {
                    if ((ace.ObjectType != null) && (ace.ObjectType.ToUpper() == PASSWORD_GUID.ToUpper()))
                    {
                        if ((ace.Trustee == "Everyone") && (ace.AceType == ADS_ACETYPE_ACCESS_DENIED_OBJECT))
                        {
                            fEveryone = true;
                        }
                        if ((ace.Trustee == @"NT AUTHORITY\SELF") && (ace.AceType == ADS_ACETYPE_ACCESS_DENIED_OBJECT))
                        {
                            fSelf = true;
                        }

                        break;
                    }
                }

                if (fEveryone || fSelf)
                {
                    return Global.RequestContants.CANT_CHANGE_PASSWORD;
                }
                else
                {
                    return string.Empty;
                }
            }
```